# Is it possible to use Sendgrid Java libraries with Google's App engine Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, email, sendgrid

I have been trying to get SendGrid to work in my Google endpoints backend using java, with Google app engine. There seems to be a few statements online about using Sendgrid with Google compute engine, but nothing with app engine..

Is it possible to use SendGrid with app engine endpoints?

Comment: SendGrid has simple REST API, why there's should be a problem to use it?   Simply use urlfetch.

Comment: I am using SendGrids java library, and with the first line, SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid(..., ...); it bombs out with service unavailable error 503. Will update question to better describe this

Comment: @cli any exception in the logs?

Comment: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
{
  "code": 503,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "",
      "reason": "backendError"
    }
  ],
  "message": ""
}

Comment: my code giving the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726873/sendgrid-not-working-in-google-app-engine-endpoints?rq=1

Comment: @Dmitry I haven't sent a single email yet, can't be over the quota, product still in testing so no limits can be reached

Comment: well, are you sure? did you check developers console?

Comment: try to make requests directly with urlfetch through rest API -- it will work. maybe your library tries to make non-https calls

Comment: @Dmitry That might be the problem, I need to ensure https communication between Google app engine and Sendgrid?

Comment: you have to read about gae's limitations. and error log you provided does not seems to be from app engine logs -- it should be more detailed and it should tell you everything you need to know. as I said, yes, you should try to use pure http/https requests (80/443 ports) or try to use sockets if you want to make requests on other ports. note that they require you to enable billing, and that's why you might getting those over quota error.

Comment: @Dmitry thank you for your advice. I have enabled billing on gae. Yes, its the error returned to my android device, will try figure out how to see those app engine logs, will help to have a more detailed response. One last thing, could using a different email for gae and sendgrid cause a problem?

Comment: Problem solved: all it was is that I was using username and password when creating an Sendgrid object, I changed it to use a key which was created on sendgrid and it worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create an google cloud endpoint using the Sendgrid java libraries.

Need to:

1. Create SendGrid account
2. Create Endpoint with SendGrid object, specifying your sendgrid key (do not use username and password)
3. Set email object with all specifics
4. Send email

[Check this for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726873/sendgrid-not-working-in-google-app-engine-endpoints/31743532#31743532)